# jQuery $.post problems (Not sending variable to PHP)

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I came across a little problem and struggling to solve it... Was wondering if you had any ideas... I have read A LOT of stackoverflow posts about the same issues, but still can't solve mine. I am workin in CodeIgniter.

I am trying to send the variable to PHP controller form the view using jQuery ($.post). Here is mine js code, that is embedded into the view:

```
$('#testbtn').on('click', function() {
        var orderValue = this.value;
        $.post('http://localhost/codeigniter/welcome/index', {val: 'myValue'}, function(data) {
            alert(data);
        });
    });
```

Here is the PHP code in the controller:

```
$a = isset($_POST['val']) ? $_POST['val'] : 'Not set yet.';
echo $a ;
```

Here is the button: `<button id="testbtn" value="thevalue">button</button>`

The button is clicked, I get the alert message with the variable and the html code of the whole page, but PHP echo doesn't change, still says: "Not set yet.".

Basically it seems to be very easy, but I can't still find the error...

Comment: Can you place here HTML-code of your #testbtn??

Comment: `<button id="testbtn" value="thevalue">Button</button>` (Accidentally mistyped)

Comment: That doesn't look like how you should be accessing POST information with codeigniter.

Comment: Then how can I access it? `$a = $this->input->post('val'); echo $a ;`- that doesn't help either

Comment: Use whole function `$.ajax`, not just shorthand `$.post` to see if result is the same. And use `async: false, ` property.

Comment: Can you var_dump($_REQUEST)

Comment: The result was the same, I have already tried that...

Comment: That is for the var_dump($_REQUEST): `array(2) { ["sec"]=> string(5) "(New)" ["col"]=> string(3) "999" }`;

Comment: Also, inspect the xhr request on the network tab in your browser developer console

Comment: Nothing.......................

Comment: Can you explain, what are you getting in alert? What variable?

Comment: I get the html of the whole page and the string that I am trying to send (`'myValue'`);

Comment: So you get what you want? What is the problem?

Comment: PHP script does not receive the variable. (You thought I am aiming at the alert message?) And actually I don't get a variable - I am getting only this "Not set yet" message.

Comment: No, i get, what you are trying to achieve. But the code you provided is legit, it should work. Maybe not enough data is provided for us to help. Problem probably is in PHP, more code provided could help.

Comment: It seems to be everything... Just to be sure, is this the write way to pass the strings? Why alert gives me the whole html message? Do I need forms in arround the button? Why am I getting the "Not set yet." message in the alert?    Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: PHP code should be placed at the beginning of file, and you should use exit; after echo.

Comment: exit(); removes the page, PHP is in the controller (basically almost at the beginning.

Comment: You can make it conditional then. For example, send something like `{val: 'myValue', action: 'test'}`, then in php `if (isset($_POST['action'])) { if ($_POST['action'] == 'test') {...} exit; }`

Comment: How come I get the result in the alert message, using the method you have provided? (Not echo-ing out)

Comment: Are you getting anything at all then?

Comment: don't follow @Tpojka recommendation of using `async:false` ...that is terrible advice!  It blocks the whole page and is being deprecated by browser vendors. There is nothing wrong with using `$.post`

Comment: Ye, I do get it as the callback now, but I do not have the motion on the page... I mean I need to dynamically modify the page using this variable, but it doesn't change the html at all, the page remains static... I need to make a SQL query and without refreshing add the items I need to the page...

Comment: Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools to see what is being sent. Then in controller do a dump of `$_POST` with no conditionals. Also if this button is in a form make sure it is `type="button"` to avoid page reload as default button will submit form

Comment: I have added the type, but the page is still static. About the dump and the browser, I am not sure, what to do... Thank you for your consideration.

Comment: F12 in browser...then go to network tab...can see all the nitty gritty for any request. Will see data sent/returned and status,headers, duration... first place to start when debugging ajax

Comment: Oh, yes.. I have remembered that, thank you. But it still gives no results. there is no data sent/returned/etc...

Comment: If nothing sent...find out why. No point debugging php until that is resolved. Can't imagine why there isn't though, you hard coded value in question

Comment: @charlietfl nothing wrong with async set to false because if there is some server time to search and get correct data, it is good to set it that way. Otherwise you'll not get right or at least complete data. For using it in good manner it is good to set loader gif before and remove it after. $.post is just shorthand of $.ajax so I asked author od question to check if that way is working.

Comment: @Tpojka that is just a complete misunderstanding of ajax and is completely wrong. There is a reason browser vendors are putting deprecation warnings in console when you use it now...it is bad practice. It blocks the whole UI , scripts, user events everything. And it certainly gives no benefit as a debugging tool

Comment: @charlietfl Thank you for this I'm going to check documentation again.

Answer (score 0):

Without diving into the code more, this would work.

HTML:

```
<button id="testbtn" value="thevalue">button</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#testbtn').on('click', function() {
        var orderValue = {"orderValue": $(this).val()};
        $.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/codeigniter/welcome/index',
        method: 'POST',
        data: orderValue,
        success: function(data) { alert(data); }
    });
```

PHP:

```
public function index() {
    $a = isset($_POST['orderValue']) ? $_POST['orderValue'] : 'Not set yet.';
    return a;
}
```

As stated in other comments though, this may not be the best practice.

Comment: This isn't valid ... `data` needs to include key/value pairs. you only have value. `data: {orderValue: data: orderValue}`

Comment: FYI..no reason using `$.post` won;t do exactly the same thing. This isn't really resolving anything

Comment: Either works.  This is valid code.  I corrected the errors with the initial post.